# How to list numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to list these numbers like:

```
1. 114
2. 115
3. 116
```

etc.. The code I have right now is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num = 0;
            int count = 114;
            while (count < 146)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num + "." + count);
                Console.Read();
                count++;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is 0=114 and nothing after.. Please help

Comment: Move your Console.Read out of your loop (put it after the closing brace). Run it again and *see* what happens.

Comment: Thanks ! How would I count the numbers by 4 or 5 instead of one?

Comment: Thanks . How do I mark you as answer?

Comment: @user2309648 You can't mark comments as answers, only actual separate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Console.Read()` blocks the loop, so it should be:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num = 0;
        int count = 114;
        while (count < 146)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num + "." + count);                
            count++;
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `for` loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 1;

    for (int count = 114; count < 146; count++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", num, count);
         num++;
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

If you had [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) inside the loop, you would need to hit the Enter key in order for the program to continue.